# When approximating $e^{.1}$ using McLauren expansion the error has $e^{.1}$ - does this mean there is an error on the error?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

When approximating $e^{.1}$ using McLauren expansion, with $n=4$, the error is $\frac{e^{.1}(.1)^{5}}{5!}$. The expression $e^.1$ is part of the error. Does this mean there is an error to the error? And then another error for that... in a loop that would just keep going?

Answer (score 4):

Actually the error is *less than* the expression.  To get a usable bound, you need to replace $e^{0.1}$ by something you know to be larger.  Say by $2$.  Then you'll know your error is less than

$$\frac{2(0.2)^5}{5!} = \frac{1}{6000000}.$$

Comment: So you are saying that instead of the $e^{.1}$ you should just use a number know to be bigger. Did you change the .1 in parenthesis to .2 on purpose? If yes, why?

Comment: @Burt  No, I changed $e^{.1}$ to $2$.  You could use $3$ instead.  But, yes, use a nicer number you know to be bigger.

Comment: I know you changed $e^{-1}$ on purpose. I'm just wondering why you changed the .1 to a .2 in the $(0.2)^5$ term.

Comment: Ah, that was just a typo. Sorry.